# PHP File Serving code

Tags: php, optimization

I've been writing a small site which is essentially just a service API for other applications but deals with the caching and serving of files. In an effort to make the site as scalable and maintainable as possible I did some research into the most efficient ways to serve files to the client, using PHP for access control.

I figured I'd probably need this sort of functionality again somewhere down the line so I decided to write a small-ish static utility class to serve up files. I'd like feedback on the overall robustness/efficiency of the code as well as comments on how well this follows the HTTP specifications. Improvements are always welcome as I haven't had a chance to really stress test the code yet.

A few of the optimizations are really targeted towards an Apache web-server, but the code itself should work on any PHP box. If anyone knows how to check for the `mod_xsendfile` module on Nginx/lighttpd accurately that would be a great addition.

```
<?php
class FileServer {
    const TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE = 8192;

    /**
     * void serveFile(string $filepath, string $realname, string $mimeType, [bool $publicFile=true, [bool $allowPartial=true, [callable $callback=false ]]])
     *  Serve the file residing at $filepath to the client.
     * @param $filepath     The absolute or relative URI to the file
     * @param $realname     The name to give the client for this file (such as in the Save dialog from a browser)
     * @param $mimeType     The desired MIME type to send with the response (allows for custom mime-types rather than just using PECLs FileInfo)
     * @param $publicFile   Whether the file is safe for public access or not (i.e you want to hide the true location of the file from clients). Optional, defaults to true
     * @param $allowPartial Whether or not to accept partial requests (via the HTTP_RANGE header) to download the file.
     * @param $callback     An optional callback to invoke before terminating the script, allows for any cleanup code to run. 
     *                          Function singature should match 'int function(int)' where the parameter indicates the status code being sent to the client.
     *                          The function should return the desired exit code
     *
     * @remarks After calling this function the script will be guaranteed to terminate on all branches after invoking $callback
     */
    public static function serveFile($filepath, $realname, $mimeType, $publicFile=true, $allowPartial=true, $callback=false) {
        if (!is_file($filepath)) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
            exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 404));
        }

        $size = filesize($filepath);
        $headers = array();

        // get all available headers
        foreach($_SERVER as $k=>$v) {
            $key = strtolower($k);
            if (strpos($key, 'http_') === 0) { $key = substr($key, 5); }
            $headers[$key] = $v;
        }
        // pick up any apache http headers that weren't in $_SERVER (need reference as to whether this is even possible?)
        if (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
            $headers += array_change_key_case(apache_request_headers());
        }

        // check if a range was specified
        $range = (isset($headers['range']) ? $headers['range'] : false);

        if ($range !== false && $allowPartial) { // need to handle a partial request
            if (($ranges = self::parseRange($range, $size)) === false) { // badly formatted range from client
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable', true, 416);
                header('Content-Range: bytes */' . $size, true);
                exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 416));
            }
        }

        // Allow for some caching optimization, although in my experience this won't hit too often from browsers.
        $ims = !empty($headers['if_modified_since']) ? $headers['if_modified_since'] : false;
        $inm = !empty($headers['if_none_match']) ? $headers['if_none_match'] : false;

        if (self::cacheControl($filepath, $ims, $inm)) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified", true, 304);
            exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 304));
        }

        if (function_exists('apache_get_modules')) { // try to optimize with apache (x-sendfile header)
            if (in_array('mod_xsendfile', apache_get_modules())) {
                // note: X-Sendfile claims to handle HTTP_RANGE headers properly,
                // so that is why this is the leading code branch
                header('X-Sendfile: ' . $filepath);
                header("Content-Type: {$mimeType}");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$realname}\"");
                exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 200));
            }
        }

        // Common headers 
        header("Content-Type: {$mimeType}", true);
        header("Accept-Ranges: " . ($acceptPartial ? 'bytes' : 'none'), true);

        // send a partial request
        if ($range !== false && $allowPartial) {
            $contentRanges = self::implodeAssoc($ranges, '-', ',');
            // send appropriate partial header info
            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content", true, 206);
            header("Content-Range: bytes {$contentRanges}/{$size}", true);

            if (($fp = fopen($filepath, 'r')) === false) {
                header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error", true, 500);
                exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 500));
            }

            foreach($ranges as $start=>$end) {
                $length = ($end - $start) + 1;

                // Open up a file stream to serve the chunked request
                if ($start > 0 && fseek($fp, $start, SEEK_SET) === -1) {
                    header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error", true, 500);
                    exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 500));
                }

                // Transfer the data, one TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE block at a time to
                // reduce the memory footprint on larger files
                $chunks = (int)($length / self::TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE);
                $delta = $length % self::TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE;

                for($i = 0; $i < $chunks; ++$i) {
                    echo fread($fp, self::TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE);
                }
                // handle the residual data that didn't align along TRANSFER_CHUNK_SIZE
                echo fread($fp, $delta); 
            }

            fclose($fp);
            exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 206));
        }

        // By now it's a pretty grim situation for file i/o.

        // Possible redirect opportunity using the Location header. Note: this only works
        // on public documents, $publicFile should be false when serving restricted content.
        // Also, the file must reside in the document root to be accessible by setting Location
        if ($publicFile && ($url = self::filepathToUrl($filepath, true)) !== false) { 
            header("Location: {$url}", true);
            exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 302));
        }

        // Give up, going to have to use PHP :)
        header("Content-Length: {$size}", true);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$realname}\"", true);
        readfile($filepath);
        exit(self::invokeCallback($callback, 200));
    }

    // Pretty self-explanatory, just a helper to abstract the way ETags are generated
    public static function generateETag($filepath, $salt='') {
        return hash('sha256', $filepath . $salt);
    }

    // Another lazy helper to validate a callback and invoke it, or return a default value
    private static function invokeCallback($callback, $response, $default=0) {
        if (is_callable($callback)) {
            return call_user_func($callback, $response);
        }
        return $default;
    }

    private static function cacheControl($filepath, $ifModifiedSince, $ifNoneMatch) {
        // Do the caching housekeeping.
        // Function returns true if the cached version is up-to-date (i.e a 304 is acceptable), or false otherwise
        $mtime = filemtime($filepath);
        $time = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $mtime);
        $etag = self::generateETag($filepath, $mtime);

        if ($ifModifiedSince !== false || $ifNoneMatch !== false) {
            if ($ifModifiedSince == $time || $etag == str_replace('"', '', stripslashes($ifNoneMatch))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // send some validation headers for cache-control later
        header('Last-Modified: ' . $time, true);
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate', true);
        header('ETag: ' . $etag, true);     

        return false;
    }

    private static function implodeAssoc($assoc, $keyValueSeparator, $entrySeparator) {
        // A really, really lazy way to implode an array by first delimiting the keys and values by one delimiter
        // then delimiting this new array by another delimiter
        return implode($entrySeparator, 
            array_map(function($k,$v) use($keyValueSeparator) {
                return "{$k}{$keyValueSeparator}{$v}";
            }, array_keys($assoc), $assoc)
        );
    }

    private static function filepathToUrl($filepath, $relative=false) {
        // normalize to *Nix path separators
        $root = str_replace('\\', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        $filepath = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($filepath));

        $relpath = str_replace($root, '', $filepath);

        if ($filepath === $relpath && $filepath[0] !== '/') // can't convert the absolute path to a URL because it's outside the document root
            return false;

        if ($relpath[0] != '/') $relpath = '/' . $relpath;
        if (!$relative) {
            $protocol = "http" . ((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'off') ? '' : 's') . '://';
            return $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $relpath;
        }

        return $relpath;        
    }

    /**
     * Parse a HTTP_RANGE header value into an array of 'start' => 'end' ranges
     * @param $range the raw HTTP_RANGE value to parse
     * @param $size the size of the file that is being partially requested
     *
     * @return an associative array of 'start' => 'end' integer pairs if the range is valid, false otherwise
     */
    private static function parseRange($range, $filesize) {
        if (!preg_match('/^bytes=\\d*-\\d*(,\d*-\d*)*$/', $range)) {
            return false;
        }

        $ranges = explode(',', substr($range, 6));
        $specs = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < count($ranges); ++$i) {
            $parts = explode('-', $ranges[$i]);
            if (empty($parts[0]) && empty($parts[1])) {
                return false; //have to specify at least one side of the range
            }

            // Try to comply with the standard as best I understand it here
            $end = !empty($parts[1]) ? intval($parts[1]) : $filesize - 1;
            $start = !empty($parts[0]) ? intval($parts[0]) : ($filesize - ($end + 1));
            if ($end > ($filesize - 1)) $end = $filesize - 1;

            if ($start > $end) {
                return false;
            }

            $specs[$start] = $end;
        }

        return $specs;
    }
}
?>
```

Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

### That's a lot of code

It looks like it works but since it's apache specific what's wrong with using [virtual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.virtual.php)? It's an apache-specific php function for serving files. I.e.

```
public static function serveFile($filepath, $realname, $mimeType, $publicFile=true, $allowPartial=true, $callback=false) {
    ...

    // do whatever and then just hand the file to apache to handle
    virtual($filepath);
    exit();
}
```

### Not testable

The biggest failing with the code as written is that you can't unit test it - I.e. you can't use [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de), mock things and verify that it handles all circumstances you think it can. The main roadblock to this is putting `exit()` directly in the same method that does things. A better idea is to do:

```
public static function whatever() {
    ...
    static::_stop();
}

protected static function _stop($reason = null) {
    exit($reason);
}
```

In this way you *can* mock the test class, or simply subclass it and override `_stop` so that it does not exit execution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I hadn't heard of the `virtual` method before today, so I'll be sure to look into that as an alternate method when it's available. Presumably it doesn't work with `range` requests but it'd be a nice alternative to the final `readfile` case on Apache servers. As for the testable aspect, I can't say I spent much time considering it as a lot of the branches are server-specific and not really something a unit-test would be able to handle anyway. Valid point though. Thanks again.

Comment: why would you presume that passing a request back to apache does not handle range requests? Code you can't test - is code you cannot be sure actually works :). Being server-specific does not affect whether code should be testable.

Comment: I said using `virtual` is unlikely to check the HTTP_RANGE header. X-Sendfile had to write specific code to handle this. Just because code does not work specifically with your chosen testing suite, does not make it `untestable`; I ran few of my own tests against this.